# Can't read a structure from text file - C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that would read structures from a TEXT file and would print it. However, my while loop doesn't work somehow and I don't know why:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct data {
     char foodName[FILENAME_MAX];
     int rating;
     double price;
 };

 FILE* openFile(char antraste[], char rezimas); <--- this function works ant it just opens a text file, so don't look into this


 int main() {

     FILE* dataText = openFile("Input data file: ", 'r');

     struct data food;

     while(fread(&food, sizeof(struct data), 1, dataText)) <--- it doesn't go inside the cycle
      {
         printf ("name = %s rating = %d price = %d\n", food.foodName, food.rating, food.price);
      }

     fclose(dataText);

     printf("Done\n");

     return 0;
 }
```

My data.txt file looks like this:

```
Pasta 4.5 2.5
Soup 3.4 1.4
Pie 4.8 3.5
```

Comment: How did you generate that file?  It looks hand-written, and your method of reading would require binary data.

Comment: Since your data is text and not a fixed size you should use `fscanf` to read it or `fgets` to read a line and `sscanf` to parse it into variables. You should also check to be sure that `dataText` is not `NULL` before using it or closing it.

Comment: `fread` reads binary data. Your file is in text format. Look into `fscanf` instead.

Comment: Another problem: You have `rating` declared as `int`, but you have floating point values in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fscanf` and not the `fread` function.
This because the `fread` expect to read a binary file, while the `fscanf` read the text file.

More detailed info on [fread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) at this link.